# Concise Bold/Italic words in ScalaTags paragraph

Tags: scala, scalatags

I'm trying to figure out the most concise way to use italics and bold font
styles in a primarily English prose page.

The only dependency:

```
import scalatags.Text.all._
```

This was the 1st version:

```
p(id:="with-italics-verbose")("""
  Earlier sentence in paragraph.
  This is a sentence with
  """, 
  i("very"),
  """
  important words, so
  """,
  b("pay attention."),
  """
  Later sentence in same paragraph.
  """
)
```

Interrupting the multiline string, dropping a separate element in, then
starting a new multiline string just for a few special words is really 
clunky, and makes editing a pain.

This is the 2nd version, using a combination of the raw function and string
interpolation:

```
p(id:="with-italics-raw-interpolate")(raw(s"""
  Earlier sentence in paragraph.
  This is a sentence with ${i("very")}, important words, so ${b("pay attention")}.
  Later sentence in same paragraph.
  """
))
```

Is that as good as I can hope for using ScalaTags?
Using the latest 0.6.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could throw in `br()` tags manually, if you really want the line-breaks. In most cases you probably don't want to be specifying the line breaks in your original code anyway, though, and if you are you should be using `p()` tags.

Barring that, triple-quotes don't need their own line, so you can run with something like

```
div(
  """
  This is the first sentence.
  The second sentence is """, i("quite"), """ fancy.
  This is the third sentence.
  """
)
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks like my intent wasn't clear, I don't want line-breaks of any kind, neither in the presentation, or the code itself. The whole paragraph should display without breaks. I'm just trying to figure out the most terse way of accomplishing that, ideally without any calls to raw(...)

Comment: Then why are you using string literals? You could just do, say, `div("I am ", i("very"), "important")`.

Comment: This is primarily a writing project, and I'm just trying to come up with the least disruptive way of writing paragraphs with the occasional italicized/bold word. The sentence after my first example addresses why I would rather not use that approach.

Basically, I want to use bold/italics, but not treat them as so special that I need to break up the paragraph/div every time I use them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it on the server:

```
import scalatags.Text.all._

div(
  h1("Welcome to Scala.js"),
  p("The ", b("server"), " added this. Time to relax ☕")
)
```

To do the same on the client, use `import scalatags.JsDom.all._`